# Regex Insert Filter on Router Beego Framework

Tags: go, beego

I try to use regex that not contain url prefix /**token** like this

```
    beego.InsertFilter("^((?!token).)*$",beego.BeforeRouter,token_construct.APIBaiscAuth("ok","ok"))
```

But not work, all url prefix still skip the filter function.

How to use regex in this function

Comment: `?<!` is [not supported](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: @Ainar-G just updated my regex, still not work